# Using UIColor in a switch statement

Tags: swift, switch-statement, uicolor

I have an array of object in my first controller and I'm passing one to modify it by modal segue. This modal view is the same to create a new object and to fill it.

In the Storyboard of this modal I have 3 TextField and 5 buttons who represent color. When the user click on one I draw a border to mark it as selected.

When I load this modal view to modify my existing object I need to draw the border of the correct button.

I have a method who do that but it needs the UIButton instance in parameter. So I was wondering if it was possible to use a switch statement to know wich color is in my object and to call the function with the good UIButton instance.

```
    switch action?.color {
        case UIColor.redColor(): setBorderColor(rougeButton)
        case UIColor.blueColor(): setBorderColor(bleuButton)
        case UIColor.yellowColor(): setBorderColor(jauneButton)
        case UIColor.greenColor(): setBorderColor(vertButton)
        case UIColor.whiteColor(): setBorderColor(blancButton)
        default:
            setBorderColor(blancButton)
            action?.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
```

Thansk in advance for your answer !

Edit :

I tried to print this color instance to see if I could transform it in other way to make the switch work.

```
println("\(action?.color)")
```

Which prints

```
Optional(UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1) // UIColor.whiteColor()
Optional(UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1) // UIColor.redColor()
```

So I don't know what could I do because it returns different things

Answer (score 2):

As is indicated by the output in your console, the 'color' property is an Optional. You need to EITHER:

1. Find a way to avoid storing it as an optional
2. Use Optional Chaining combined with Optional Binding before your switch statement:

   ```
   if let colorUnwrapped = action?.color {
   switch colorUnwrapped {
      //etc
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Since the type of `action?.color` is `UIColor?` (`Optional<UIColor>`), you have to unwrap it:

```
if let actionColor = action?.color {
    switch actionColor {
    case UIColor.redColor(): setBorderColor(rougeButton)
    case UIColor.blueColor(): setBorderColor(bleuButton)
    case UIColor.yellowColor(): setBorderColor(jauneButton)
    case UIColor.greenColor(): setBorderColor(vertButton)
    case UIColor.whiteColor(): setBorderColor(blancButton)
    default:
        setBorderColor(blancButton)
        action?.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
else {
    setBorderColor(blancButton)
    action?.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

OR use enum case pattern:

```
switch action?.color {
case .Some(UIColor.redColor()): setBorderColor(rougeButton)
case .Some(UIColor.blueColor()): setBorderColor(bleuButton)
case .Some(UIColor.yellowColor()): setBorderColor(jauneButton)
case .Some(UIColor.greenColor()): setBorderColor(vertButton)
case .Some(UIColor.whiteColor()): setBorderColor(blancButton)
default:
    setBorderColor(blancButton)
    action?.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the error was not just about the wrapped UIColor but that I couldn't put an object in a switch. It works fine now, Thanks !